# Handling concurrency in CQRS approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, architecture, cqrs

I'm using the CQRS approach in my architecture, as an example, I have a command like:

```
public class ModifyDepartmentInformationCommand
{
    public ModifyDepartmentInformationCommand() { }
    public ModifyDepartmentInformationCommand(int departmentId, string departmentName, byte[] version)
    {
        DepartmentId = departmentId;
        DepartmentName = departmentName;
        Version = version;
    }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }                 
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }        
}
```

Its handler looks like:

```
 public class ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandHandler : 
    IRequestHandler<ModifyDepartmentInformationCommand, ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandResult>
 {
    private readonly IMgpCommandContext _mgpCommandContext;

    public ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandHandler(IMgpCommandContext mgpCommandContext)
    {
        _mgpCommandContext = mgpCommandContext;            
    }

    public ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandResult Execute(ModifyDepartmentInformationCommand request)
    {            
        new ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandValidator().ValidateAndThrow(request);
        var department = _mgpCommandContext.Departments.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == request.DepartmentId);
        if (department == null) { throw new ApplicationException("DepartmentDoesNotExist", "There is no such department."); }
        department.ModifyInformation(request.Version, request.DepartmentName);
        _mgpCommandContext.SaveChanges();
        return new ModifyDepartmentInformationCommandResult();                                                           
    }
}
```

As you see `Version` is used as the concurrency token. It is passed with the command, and in the command handler passed to the department's domain entity operation ModifyInformation, which sets the version:

```
public class Department
{
    ...

    public void ModifyInformation(byte[] version, string departmentName)
    {
        Version = version;
        Name = departmentName;

        new DepartmentValidator().ValidateAndThrow(this);
    } 
}
```

Because the Version property on the Department domain entity is mapped using EF Code First as follows:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("Department").Property(p => p.Version).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken(); ;          
 }
```

...concurrency is detected correctly from the moment SaveChanges is executed on the context.

That's how it works now... the question I have is related to the fact that I have one concurrency token on department level. So, if I have commands that each modify different properties of a department, the same concurrency token is used.

As a result, if two users query department X, and user 1 uses a command to change the department name and user 2 uses another command to change some other property of department; then the second user that submits the command may still get a concurrency violation even if it's not the same property that was modified.

Is this the right approach, or is there a better way to handle concurrency in commands, like using multiple concurrency tokens for an entity? What approach is generally taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose right approach. Also, you can split the department configuration into several logical parts, for example: common parameters, security, etc. Each part would be considered in isolation and each part will have its own version.